# where can I get trial of websphere process server

Tags: websphere

I am unable to locate trial version of websphere  process server. I want to get my hands on this software. Or in other words what is best way to learn about this software?

Answer (score 0):

You can download a tial on that page:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/was/

You can also take a look on that page for more trial:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/

Regards,
Jim

Comment: Hi Jimmy, I am not talking about WAS but I asked about WPS server.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the mistake. The only informations you can have on IBM website are demo for WPS. http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/search.jsp?pn=WebSphere+Process+Server

Answer (score 0):

About tutorials:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0305_issw/recommendedreading.html

http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/blueedition/blue_connectors/

And infocenter:

publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.was_v8/plugin_coverpage.html

Regards,
Jim.